# Invalid anonymous type member error

Tags: c#

This issue is along the lines of a previous issue. I'm getting an invalid anonymous type member error. Yet I have gone through to fix it and make sure it matches up with the given data I a trying to pull.

```
var branches = ctx.tblCodeBrokBranches.Where(comp => comp.BrokOffID == 1);
                var activeBrokerLocs = branches.Select(b => new
                {
                    b.BrokOffID.ToString(), //Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.
                    b.BrokBranch
                })
                                .AsEnumerable()
                                .Select(b => new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Value = b.BrokOffID.ToString(),
                                    Text = b.BrokBranch
                                });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless the member name can be inferred from a property or field expression, you'll have to give the member an explicit name:

```
var activeBrokerLocs = branches.Select(b => new
{
    BrokOffID = b.BrokOffID.ToString(),
    b.BrokBranch
})...
```

But from your comments, it appears `BrokOffID` is already a string. In that case, you do not need to call `ToString` at all and you can let C# infer the member name:

```
var activeBrokerLocs = branches.Select(b => new
{
    b.BrokOffID,
    b.BrokBranch
})...
```

Comment: I adjusted it to that you suggested but now when I run a test I am getting a LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression error.